# Can't start remote WildFly with ssh

Tags: ssh, init.d

When executing remote script with SSH:

```
ssh user@192.168.0.10 -t sudo /etc/init.d/wildfly start
```

WildFly not started.
If I run

```
ssh user@192.168.0.10 -t /home/user/my.sh
```

my.sh:

```
!#/bin/bash
sudo /etc/init.d/wildfly start
sleep 10
```

WildFly starting and after 10 sec, when ssh connection closed WF stopped.
If I connect "manually" with "ssh user@192.168.0.10" and then type in console "sudo /etc/init.d/wildfly start" - no problem.

init.d/wildfly: http://pastebin.com/UDxmEYRZ

How I can start WildFly without manually enter each command in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nohup` could be what you want:

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

```
sudo nohup /etc/init.d/wildfly start
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your command in single quotation  `' '` : 
`ssh user@192.168.0.10  'sudo /etc/init.d/wildfly start'`
And also set timeout parameter more in `sshd.conf`